# Switching a bulb ON and OFF using toggle switch in Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Kindly help me in the Arduino code as I am new in this field. I have Arduino code that turns the light in bulb ON and OFF using toggle switch. It is successfully running and giving output.

The following is the code:

```
int buttonPinBulb = 11;
int relay1 = 10;

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPinBulb, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int buttonBulb = digitalRead(buttonPinBulb);
  
  if(buttonBulb == HIGH){
    digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
  }
  Serial.println(buttonBulb);
}
```

**Before following suggestion in the comment, the output was:**

[image: when switch is OFF]

[image: when switch is ON]

**Issue**

Bulb is turning ON and OFF when I toggle switch ON and OFF, and the output is showing on serial monitor continuously. But I want only one value that is not repeated. Like if I toggle the switch ON, then the value shown on serial monitor should be 1 and not 11111111....

Please help me about that. How can I do that?

**After following suggestion in the comment, the code is:**

```
int buttonPinBulb = 11;
int relay1 = 10;
int buttonBulb;
void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPinBulb, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(buttonBulb);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  buttonBulb = digitalRead(buttonPinBulb);
  
  if(buttonBulb == HIGH){
    digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
  }
 //Serial.println(buttonBulb);
}
```

**And the output was:**
[image: either the switch is OFF or ON the value is the same it should change when I switch ON]

Comment: Try using a global variable to store the previous state, and only do the print if it changes

Comment: @Buddy I have use it as global variable but it gives me 0 the first state when I change the state it did not change. I use the Serial.println(buttonBulb); in setup method and use a buttonBulb variable as global

Comment: Show that code if you have tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: @kaylum it is working and giving me the output but I want different output as it giving me continous 1's or 0's but I want only 1 and 0 in the output

Comment: Yes I know. But you have been given a suggestion to use a global variable which should work if you did it right. You said you tried that but it didn't work so show that code.

Comment: @kaylum it's working but only gives one output on serial monitor as the switch is off when I on the switch it remains 0. However it should change to 1

Comment: It's not "working" if it doesn't do exactly as you want. Show the code. You obviously have an error. Can't tell you what if you don't show it.

Comment: @kaylum how do I show to you the whole process that what I want because I can't do it in a comment

Comment: Click [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64181338/edit) and update the question with your attempt to make the `println` only print on state change.

Comment: @kaylum I have just edited my question please review it

Comment: Why did you comment out the `println` in `loop`? The point of using the global variable is so that you can check the current state with the previous state and call the `println` if the state changes.

Comment: @kaylum because it is showing the value again and again I don't want it. I want only 1 and 0 that should not repeat when the state change

Comment: `int currentState = digitalRead(buttonPinBulb); if (currentState != buttonBulb) {buttonBulb = currentState; Serial.println(buttonBulb);}`. As I said, check the state. That is, only print if the state changes.

Comment: @kaylum thank you very much it's now working. Please tell me one thing more if I send the buttonBulb value to database then would it store their as showing on the serial monitor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222523/discussion-between-tinycoder-and-kaylum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global variable to store the current status of the button.

You may also want to [debounce](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/electronics/debounce.html) your button (using [`millis()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) in the below example, unless the debouncing is already done in hardware) - especially when you want to update a database each time the status changes.

```cpp
int buttonPinBulb = 11;
int relay1 = 10;
int currentStatus = LOW;

// Debounce
unsigned long lastMillis = 0;
const unsigned long debounceTime = 100; // 100ms wait

void setup() {

    pinMode(buttonPinBulb, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {

    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

    if ( (currentMillis - lastMillis > debounceTime)
         || (currentMillis < lastMillis)) {  // protect against overflow
        
        int buttonBulb = digitalRead(buttonPinBulb);

        if (buttonBulb != currentStatus) {

            digitalWrite(relay1, buttonBulb);
            Serial.println(buttonBulb);
            currentStatus = buttonBulb;

            // update database here
        }

        lastMillis = currentMillis; 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Denny_ds How can I send this value to database and also I want want to get value from database? Like, if I switch ON or OFF then the buttonBulb value goes to database and then come from database to control the like switch.

Comment: @TinyCoder I think it would be better to create a separate question regarding database access from Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

As you have been told in comments, just store the current value of the pin and issue `digitalWrite ()` only if a change is required.

```
ccesfully running and giving output. The following is the code:

int buttonPinBulb = 11;
int relay1 = 10;
int curRel1;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(buttonPinBulb, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
    curRel1 = digitalRead(relay1);
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
    int buttonBulb = digitalRead(buttonPinBulb);
  
    if(buttonBulb == HIGH)
    {
        digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
    }
 
    if (buttonBulb != curRel1)
    {
        Serial.println(buttonBulb);
        curRel1 = buttonBulb;
    }
}
```

You could also update `curRel1` in `loop()` calling `digitalRead()`.